# Postgres: drop foreign key constraint query getting stuck

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I wanted to remove all foreign key constraints from a schema. I was successful in dropping constraints from most of the tables but in few of them drop foreign key constraint query is getting stuck.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT fkey_name;
```

I tried truncate cascade but it was also getting stuck. I deleted all rows from both the tables manually. Still getting stuck.

Edits: By getting stuck I mean query continues running for long time without any error message even though tables are empty.

Comment: Define "getting stuck". [Edit] the question and tell us what you observe, including any messages or errors.

Comment: Something is holding a lock on `table_name` - check for long running transactions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid exclusive access locks on referenced tables when DROPping in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145189/avoid-exclusive-access-locks-on-referenced-tables-when-dropping-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for any dead locks using

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

If any then kill and run below sql,and then drop using

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid);
```

If Not solved check for any virtual transaction

```
SELECT database, gid FROM pg_prepared_xacts;
```

Rollback using

> ROLLBACK PREPARED 'gid';